# Spring Cloud Contract- Stub runner remote resolution of stub jar

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to lookup the stub jar from nexus using

```
public StubRunnerRule rule = new StubRunnerRule()
            .downloadStub("group", "artifact")
            .repoRoot("https://nexus-repo-path/content/repositories/snapshots/")
            .stubsMode(StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE);
```

And it all works ok.

I however, was hoping that the repoRoot would take in a non SNAPSHOT or RELEASE path, something like https://nexus-repo-path/content/repositories/.

So, that once the stub jar is finalised and available in releases repo, I dont need to adjust my tests.

Is that a fair understanding and expectation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using *Nexus 2 or 3*, you can configure a `group` repository where you can add your snapshots and releases repository.

Then if you use this `group` repository, it will go through each repository enlisted and so it will find your snapshots and releases.

I guess you can do the same with *Artifactory* or the like as this concept is very common for maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it won't. You'll have to change the repo root for snapshots and release versions.

Comment: Do you think this enhancement is worth adding?

Comment: I think it's actually very repo specific and you can't assume any concrete naming out of the box. You can create an issue and we can discuss it there